# How to read all elements with in the menu list

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium-webdriver, can someone help me to read the below menu list, and click any of one elements in the menu list?

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="menu">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://www.madbatter.com/index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="currentlink" href="http://www.madbatter.com/menus.html" classname="currentlink">Menu Samples</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://www.madbatter.com/directions.html">Directions</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="hours.html">Restaurant Hours</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="entertainment.html">Entertainment</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="events.html">Upcoming Events</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://www.madbatter.com/art-shows.html">Art Exhibits</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://www.madbatter.com/reviews.html">Reviews & Awards</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://www.madbatter.com/private-events.html">Private Group Events</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://www.madbatter.com/shop_front.html">Shop Online</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://www.madbatter.com/giftcards2.html">Gift Cards</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="secondary">
            <select>
        </nav>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <p>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
```

I try this code for read all elements with in the menu list its not working.

```java
List<WebElement> elements = dr.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='menu']"));
```

Comment: Try to find by xpath , For ex : 4th menu xpath is `//*[@id="menu"]/nav/ul[1]/li[4]/a`

Comment: yea its static, I need to read all elements in the menulist using List<WebElement>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this xpath

```
 //div[@id='menu']/nav/ul/li/a
```

I hope it will works to collect all web elements into list as per your requirement.

Thank You